# Socket disconnects in iOS5 when lock key pressed

Tags: sockets, button, ios5, locking, disconnect

My iPhone application is based on remote desktop protocol which communcates with PC using socket programming. Everything works fine in iOS4, but now i encounter an issue with iOS5 based device.

My socket get's disconnected when user presses lock button in iOS5 based devices. I have developed a cocoa based static socket library which does all communication for my iphone app.

FYI: I just call a function exposed from my library to start the communication.  I call it as a background thread using
[self performSelectorInBackGround:@selector(triggerCommunication:) withObject:IP_Address];

a. Why does the socket disconnects on pressing lock button in iOS5 ?
b. Is there a way to prevent the socket from not being disconnect?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we compile with iOS5 SDK, and run application, then socket disconnects on clicking lock button.

I recompiled my application with iOS4 SDK and tested my application on iOS5 based iPhone. And now socket didnot disconnect even after locking!.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't really the answer, you'll find that the app does disconnect after about 15 minutes (even with iOS 4). To maintain your connection even when the phone is locked or your app is backgrounded you need to register for VOIP services, and set the relevant flags on the socket you are using to connect to the PC. Then you need to install a background handler for maintain the socket connection.

Comment: 1. How can we set VOIP services? 2. Which flags to set on socket? I am using c code , cocoa static libraries. Are such flags available?